# Substitute DataPortal in .net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, csla

I need ideas of how can I substitute the DataPortal model, so I dont use any portals, instead of that I want return object, table or DataSet and to attach any of these to the report on my website.

```
    public static CustomizeCourseCompletionWithModuleList GetCustomizeCourseCompletionWithModuleList()
    {
        var cmd = new StoredProcedure
        {
            CommandText = "CustomizeCourseCompletionWithModuleSelectById",
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", DBNull.Value);
        return DataPortal.Fetch<CustomizeCourseCompletionWithModuleList>(cmd);
    }
```

Comment: You should add a tag for whatever program uses "DataPortal.Fetch" and then remove "asp-classic".

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking. can you clarify? Are you wanting to not use any of csla?

Comment: By returning DataPortal, it goes through 60 files so I can get the whole information, since services are not needed, because it can be done local, I need to remove service related DataPortal and to make it return my business object or datatable so I can sort it and operate with it easily. Also I will need it because of the pagination, I dont have need to load all of the pages when the report is called, but only those records which are on the selected page. I hope I explained my idea enough considering my English bad.

Comment: What do you mean by "goes through 60 files?"  Do you mean it winds its way through the Csla framework code before getting to the DataPortal_Fetch implementation?  If so I wouldn't worry about that; your DB access is going to be the heavy cost for performance.  Also, you shouldn't have any System.Data classes in the static factory method, that should all be in the DataPortal_Fetch method of your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fighting the framework, which will not end well.  When you're building your application on csla you should return csla business objects, and your ui should never see things such as data tables.  Those are data access technologies that your csla objects can use to load themselves but should be an implementation detail not exposed by your business layer.

Comment: By returning DataPortal, it goes through 60 files so I can get the whole information, since services are not needed, because it can be done local, I need to remove service related DataPortal and to make it return my business object or datatable so I can sort it and operate with it easily. Also I will need it because of the pagination, I dont have need to load all of the pages when the report is called, but only those records which are on the selected page. I hope I explained my idea enough considering my English bad.

Comment: If you have a remote data portal configured, but don't need it in this particular case, you can decorate your DataPortal_Fetch method with the RunLocal attribute, which means the code in your DataPortal_Fetch will not cross the wire and all run on the client (or the Asp.Net server, if this is an Asp.Net application).  If you're worried about the code the DataPortal ends up running between the .Fetch and calling DataPortal_Fetch, I wouldn't.  Its more likely the DB access will take more time than the code.

Comment: Well, I am really beginner with asp .net and still trying to understand the concepts and the cycles which information do till the final result shows of. You are doing pretty much work, when asking question which I should answer first to myself and then to you, for what I give you a BIG thank. So to the question : the whole idea of this is, in the close future they are planning to remove the services used in this project since everything is on 1 server and they dont have to use them, and when I import data to DataGridView with this method it completely fulfill it no matter how many rows I have.

Comment: And when there are a lot of rows I am using pagination so I can have 15 records per page. My idea is when I make a report I don't want to load at first the whole data in my gridview but only 15 rows, when I click on the 2nd page, another 15 and so on. Did I make myself clear or I should try more ? :) Thanks in advance again. Consider I am beginner but I do have the will to learn fast

Comment: @lpstr That's the problem; in Csla, the dataportal does much more than the enabling of mobile business objects.  It also does a lot of the work, like proplerly marking the BO as dirty or clean, and old or new.  Its what sets up the rules for the type and the state manager (FieldManager).  If you want to do this you can, but you'd pretty much have to remove Csla in one shot, and then you need to have your own answer for the features it provides, such as the rule engine, state management, dirty / new tracking, etc etc.  Replacing everything Csla does for you is non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. You made it pretty clear and I believe I understand the need of changing my plan asap.